# We're in Physics Today!

Tags: discussion

The question [Can I compute the mass of a coin based on the sound of its fall?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121879/can-i-compute-the-mass-of-a-coin-based-on-the-sound-of-its-fall) has appeared on the [Physics Today Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/PhysicsToday/posts/10154354597660164).

Well done to all who contributed to that question. It has to be good for the Physics SE to get this sort of publicity.

I've been periodically annoyed by the 200 rep/day limit, but poor alemi has been stung by it big time - that limit has cost over 1000 rep points. Can the mods pull a string somewhere?

Comment: You know, once the question is old enough (a day?), you can gift your own rep to an answer with a bounty ;) "Reward existing answer" is one of the bounty reasons in fact.

Comment: The reason the rep-cap makes sense is that we use rep to control access to site features that take experience and judgement to use well. A single great post probably shouldn't give someone access to close/re-open powers a day or two after joining the site...

Comment: It was a lot of fun to answer.  I appreciate the concern for the lost rep but I'm happy to try to earn it the hard way.  I'll just have to come up with some other good answers.  I feel bad for Floris, he hasn't gotten as many upvotes on his answer as he deserves (comparatively).

Comment: I think of it like this: the function which maps number (or rate) of upvotes to total reputation gained is linear up to a certain point and then tapers off. Of course this is not the way it's implemented, but the rep cap kind of has that effect. And I think that's more or less intentional, for the reasons dmckee said and also to reward a pattern of good answers rather than isolated big hits. So if you look at it that way, it's not like anyone has been "cheated" out of a large amount of reputation (at least not due to the cap). But I don't know if you see it that way, @alemi.

Comment: What exactly is the merit of "this sort of publicity"? Maybe in the end it might reach someone good who didn't know about StackExchange, but -to put it harsh but accurately- it will definitely lead to more pleb users.

Comment: @NikolajK: *it will definitely lead to more pleb users* - Physics Today is not a mainstream publication. It's more like New Scientist except possibly more specialised. I hope it will lead to more **interested** site members.

Comment: @JohnRennie: It means more upvotes on the questions accessible to people who don't study the sciences, but like watching the sky ;)

Comment: @NikolajK exactly, it will help establishing Physics SE as a to everybody comprehensible popular science site by attracting the corresponding audience ;-)

Comment: @ChrisWhite - BMS did just that! Really appreciate the magnanimity :) But bounty goes to the highest upvoted answer, which is well-deserved here, which means Floris' answer, with 74 upvotes at this instant, will suffer again. And this is worthy of being debated.

Comment: @alemi - don't feel bad. I am quite content with second place on this one - and at least I'm not getting stung by the rep-cap nearly as much as you are... :-) . Still hoping it might get me to a gold badge. I do wonder whether the OP is ever going to accept an answer.

Comment: @Floris Perhaps he'd like to accept both answers and just can't decide :)

Comment: @New_new_newbie bounty can be manually awarded to any answer - only if you let the clock run out does it get automatically awarded...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To address the question part of this: no, there are no strings we can pull; the only way to get someone a large amount of reputation exceeding the 200/day limit is a bounty.

Comment: Odd that this got a downvote.

Comment: @KyleKanos meh, it's not uncommon that a factual post about the system or policy gets downvoted. I guess some people want to express their disapproval of the way things work.